# How does 6 colour printing affect a CMYK image?

Tags: print-design, cmyk, image-quality

I'm going to use the [Epson Artisan 1430](https://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/jsp/Product.do?sku=C11CB53201) inkjet printer, which uses 6 inks, for my project to do sublimation. Will this have any effect on the colour or resolution of my image?

Comment: I think you should add more details such as: on what material will this be printed on and if you mean you'll print on a transfer or not. One thing I'm quite certain, the CMYK conversion will not affect the resolution and if you print in 6 colors, you might in fact get a very nice result or not see much (if any) difference with CMYK. What can affect the quality and color is probably more the material you'll use to print that image on, and if it's a transfer, the material where it will be applied.

Answer (score 1):

The CMYK has nothing to do to resolution.

It does not "damage" the color either. Actually there is nothing you cand do but send it as RGB or CMYK.

An Inkjet printer makes its own internal transformation, in this case if the ammount of cyan or magenta is low for light colors, pastel ones, simply it uses the light color, and if you need a more vivid one it uses the normal cartridge. In this type of 6 color printer the improvement is on the light colors, where you could tend to see the dots of thoose 2 inks.

You just need to do some print tests before any project. Embed the necesary profiles.